# How do I use pytest-mock with modules and correct import order

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock

I am totally new to `pytest-mock`. My project layout looks like this:

```
src
  pull
    app.py
  utils
    sftp.py
tests
  test_pull.py
```

In `app.py` I have this:

```
from src.utils.sftp import list_files

def handler():
    response = list_files()
```

In `sftp.py` I have this:

```
def list_files():
    ...
```

Trying to write a pytest which has `list_files` mocked.

```
from src.pull.app import handler

def test_pulling(mocker):
    mocker.patch('src.utils.sftp.list_files', return_value=["something"])
```

This however does not work because, I believe because the import inside `app.py` is evaluated first. It works, when I change `app.py` and do a local import.

```
def handler():
    from src.utils.sftp import list_files
    response = list_files()
```

Is there a better way to set this up? Ideally I don't want to be dependant on the import order - another developer might revert the local import and break the test.

Comment: what is `list_folder_private_key` ?

Comment: sorry, that was a leftover. I updated the snippets to reflect the correct name.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reloading the module will work and won't require other changes

```
def test_pulling(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(src.utils.sftp, 'list_files', MagicMock(return_value="mock"))
    importlib.reload(src.pull.app)
    assert handler() == "mock"
```

however, sometimes it's an indication that you may need to refactor and use some [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), like

```
def handler(lf=None):
    response = lf() if lf else list_files()
    return response
```

and the test would be as simple as

```
def test_pulling_2():
    assert handler(MagicMock(return_value="mock2")) == "mock2"
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks a lot Diego!